# Large Sized HDD not recognized correctly?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ext4, fdisk

Hello I have a question with newly installed HDD for my ubuntu file server.

```
Motherboard: P7P55D-E LX<br>
New HDD: WD NAS RED 4TB<br>
OS : Ubuntu 14.04.1<br><br>
----------------------------------------------------------------<br>
jpark@data-01:~$ df -hT<br>
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on<br>
/dev/sda1      ext4      909G  861G  1.8G 100% /<br>
none           tmpfs     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup<br>
udev           devtmpfs  2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev<br>
tmpfs          tmpfs     396M  1.8M  394M   1% /run<br>
none           tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock<br>
none           tmpfs     2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm<br>
none           tmpfs     100M     0  100M   0% /run/user<br>
/dev/sdc1      ext4      917G  201G  671G  23% /media/disk/data2<br>
/dev/sdb1      ext4      917G  819G   52G  95% /media/disk/data1<br>
/dev/sdd1      ext4      2.0T   71M  1.9T   1% /media/disk/data<br>
```

---

```
-disk:1<br>
       description: ATA Disk<br>
       product: WDC WD40EFRX-68W<br>
       vendor: Western Digital<br>
       physical id: 0.1.0<br>
       bus info: scsi@1:0.1.0<br>
       logical name: /dev/sdd<br>
       version: 82.0<br>
       serial: WD-WCC4E3XKVN37<br>
       size: 3726GiB (4TB)<br>
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos<br>
       configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=4096 signature=0415ebdd<br><br>
  *-disk<br>
       description: ATA Disk<br>
       product: WDC WD10EALS-00Z<br>
       vendor: Western Digital<br>
       physical id: 0.0.0<br>
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0<br>
       logical name: /dev/sde<br>
       version: 05.0<br>
       serial: WD-WCATR0664811<br>
       size: 931GiB (1TB)<br>
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos<br>
       configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=40b85ede<br>
```

---

The system know the capacity of this new drive is 4TB, but after
ext4 formatting and mountinging it to the point. Only 2TB.?

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Did you partition it with MBR(msdos), not the required gpt? Post this: `sudo parted -l`  details:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Then launch GParted and switch to your new drive. Choose `Device → Create Partition Table` and choose "GPT". **If you apply this, all data on your HDD will be lost, so make sure to back it up if there is any.** Then make a new partition using GParted and make sure its ext4 and takes up all space available.